# Unit testing highly coupled code in .net; reflection to inject mocks?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Let's say I have a bunch of classes that look something like...

```
class Foo{
  private Bar highlyCoupled = new highlyCoupled();

  public bool DoTheThing(){
    return highlyCoupled.doesTheThing();
  } 
}
```

Is it possible to use reflection to open up foo and inject (duck-punch may be a more correct term) some sort of mockHighlyCoupled in the place of highlyCoupled?

What about in this situation...

```
class DoubleFoo : Foo{
  public bool DoTheOtherThing(){
    return DoTheThing();
  }
}
```

Can the inherited highlyCoupled have a mock inserted in it's place?

Refactoring the code so as to not require reflection isn't possible, unfortunately.

Comment: Without some serious refactoring, your tests may be very brittle.

Comment: So what are you asking?  Can you use reflection to set private members?  Yes, you can.  Are you having trouble doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't refactor using a mocking framework could make this a bit easier for you. For Example:

TypeMock:

```
var fakeType = Isolate.Fake.Instance<SomeType>();
ObjectState.SetField(fakeType, "_somePrivateField", myValue);
```

Moq:

```
var fakeType = new Mock<SomeType>()
fakeType.Protected().Setup<SomeType>("_somePrivateField").Returns(myValue);
```

To be honest I haven't actually tried this out with Moq but I think it will do what you need.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the most useful answer.  It didn't seem like a very unique situation, to see it answered in a framework verifies that.

Comment: What version of Moq has the `Protected()` method? I just downloaded Moq and I need to inject mocks into private fields that would otherwise be composed by MEF at runtime.

Comment: Should be in the latest version according to the documentation. http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart#Miscellaneous

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use reflection and a mocked type, but that type has to inherit from the original type (FieldInfo.SetValue will fail otherwise).

```
void Main()
{
    var bar = new Bar();
    var type = typeof(Bar);
    // Get the type and fields of FieldInfoClass.
    var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    fields[0].SetValue(bar, new FooMock()); // you can use new Foo() here too.
    bar.Print();
}

class Foo {
    public int i = 0;
}

class FooMock : Foo {
}

class Bar {
    private Foo foo = new Foo();

    public void Print() {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't refactor at all (make `highlyCoupled` protected), then you're stuck using reflection.  That will let you set the value of `highlyCoupled` without modification.

Answer (score 0):

I generally agree with Rob; if you can't refactor this in order to make the dependency more loosely coupled (at least allow a derived class like a test proxy to override its default value), then reflection to set the value despite its visibility is pretty much the only way you can go.

The absolute least you could do is make the dependency protected. If this is possible now or at any point in the future, do it:

```
class Foo{
  protected Bar highlyCoupled = new highlyCoupled();

  public bool DoTheThing(){
    return highlyCoupled.doesTheThing();
  } 
}

...

//in your test suite    
class FooTestProxy:Foo
{
   public FooTestProxy(Bar testMock)
   {
      highlyCoupled = testMock;
   }   
}

//now when testing, instantiate your test proxy and pass it the mocked object
```